# Cannot post comments if I don't post a website?

Tags: comments

I have a severe problem with my comment template.
For some reason comments won't show up unless somebody also clicks on the website field. It's not necessary to actually post a website, but you have to click on the field, otherwise the comment just won't show up.
Here's [my website](http://www.zoomingjapan.com) so you can try yourself.

Here's my comment.php: http://pastebin.com/pgpQ2Cx3
And here my comment-template.php (which I haven't changed but maybe a plugin did): http://pastebin.com/5zaubXWm

Any ideas? :(
I already tried various things modifying my comment.php, but nothing worked.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing line 152 in your comments-template.php file from:

```
if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' == $url )
```

to  `if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' == $url || 'Website' == $url)`

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. I modified the template, but it didn't work. Still the same problem as before.

Comment: Hello again. I got it to work by changing the code in my comment.php file back to the original and I modified it all again, completely different this time, though. Now it works. I think it's because my theme has a very weird problem with "onfocus" with textareas ... very annoying. No idea how to fix that. Thanks for trying to help! :)